# Xampp VirtualHost config with custom folder (403 error)

Tags: virtualhost

***SOLVED***
I know this is a common question that was answered many times, but I read ALL the answers and I try them all, and still can not solve it.
I want create a virtual host to solve a path issue using include_once, I want the same command working in my xampp local and in my webhost (I am newbie with php and xampp).

For this I create a virtual host how it was recomended.
Starting by including in the hosts windows file this:

```
127.0.0.1 argentinaembalajes.local
127.0.0.1 www.argentinaembalajes.local
```

then I set the virtual host in httpd.vhosts.conf:

```
## localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/webpages/"
    ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>

 ##Argentina Embalajes
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName argentinaembalajes.local
    DocumentRoot C:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/webpages/argentinaembalajes/
    ErrorLog "C:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/webpages/argentinaembalajes/mysite-error_log"
    CustomLog "C:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/webpages/argentinaembalajes/mysite-access_log" common
    <Directory "C:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/webpages/argentinaembalajes/">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I try many versions of those configs with "/" or with "\", Server Alias, with different group of permissions, without logfiles, etc.
myUserName is administrator, But I try always executing xampp as administrator, each time I test and fail, I close xampp and open again.

The httpd.conf is set like this:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/webpages"
<Directory "C:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/webpages">
```

I also try to change in the same file:

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

To: User myUserName

Then I see some people include above the virtual host tag:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
```

Or inside the tag the site name with different ports, not sure how all that should be used and what is for.

I get always this error from the apache:
**"443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name"**

Without the virtual host works fine Apache. So I imagine that I am doing many things wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think is about ssl, my site is very basic.
Ok now I change all that for this and it WORKS!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName argentinaembalajes.local
    DocumentRoot C:/Users/myUserName/webpages/argentinaembalajes/
    <Directory "C:/Users/myUserName/Desktop/webpages/argentinaembalajes/">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Ok it works if I remove all the extra permisions, which is weird, because I did that in different combinations before and nothing happen.  Maybe was some other thing that was wrong when I try those.
I spent all day with this trying diffent things, then few min before I make the question was fixed..  Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, hopefully a helpful guess, but this sounds like an issue with your SSL certificate. Does it include the URL of the virtual host?

For example, I have seen cases where company buys a certificate for "www.company.com", then they decide that for some special promotion, they want to have "promotion.company.com". Well guess what, it doesn't work. But if they'd purchased a certificate with wild cards, e.g., "*.company.com", they'd be fine.

Your issue might be the certificate doesn't like the ":8080" for example.

Comment: Thanks for your time.